# File not found error when uploading file using CSOM

Tags: 2013, document-library, file-upload, csom

I am using following code to upload file at the following location but getting **File Not Found** error at last line "clientcontext.ExecuteQuery();"

```
using (ClientContext clientcontext = new ClientContext(txtSiteURL.Text))
{
      string fileToUpload = @"c:\test.txt";
      String fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileToUpload);

      Folder folder = clientcontext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Docs").RootFolder;

      string documentUrl = txtSiteURL.Text + "/Docs/" + fileName;

      FileCreationInformation fci = new FileCreationInformation();
      fci.Overwrite = true;
      fci.Url = documentUrl;
      fci.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileToUpload );

      Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadedFile = folder.Files.Add(fci);
      clientcontext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/a/9849835/318776

Comment: I used the above code and only changed one line "string target = "http://myserver/sites/website/Documents/" + fileName;" but getting same error.

Comment: Taking a clue from your linkI found what the problem was. My path defined in "target" was wrong. I was using name "Documents" in URL when in fact its internal name is "Shared Documents"

Comment: in my case it was the `/` character in filename

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing line 8 from your code with this:

```
string documentUrl = txtSiteURL.Text + "Docs/" + fileName;
```

If the `txtSiteURL.Text` parameter already comes with a `/` at the end. the `"/Docs/"` string will cause a double forward slash in the url, and this bad url will cause a "File Not Found" error. (At least this was what caused that same error for me)

Also, try to debug that line and double check the `fileName` string does not generate problems like this, and check for other issues or typos.

Fixing the `url` resolved the `"File Not Found"` error for me.